# How to reduce 1 sec from the given time?

Tags: bash, shell, time

My shell script is reading time from user say `02:00:00`

How do i reduce 1 second from this, ie i require the output as `01:59:59`

Comment: Note that `date -d` is what you want unless you enjoy banging your head against the wall, but be aware that this only works with `GNU date` and is highly unportable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
M=$(date +%s -d "02:00:00")
M=$(($M - 1))
date +%H:%M:%S -d @$M
```

Answer (score 8):

just tell `date` you want the time 1s ago:

```
kent$ str="02:00:00"
kent$ date -d "1 sec ago $str" +%H:%M:%S           
01:59:59
```

Answer (score 8):

One more variant:

```
$ date +'%H:%M:%S' -d"02:00:00 last second"
01:59:59
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the accepted answer but with a slightly better code style:

```
M=$(date +%s -d '02:00:00')
((M--))
date +%T -d "@$M"
```

And you can condense it into one line if you want:

```
date +%T -d "@$(($(date +%s -d '02:00:00')-1))"
```

#### But!

After fooling around with the `date` command I came up with this:

```
date +%T -d '-1 seconds 02:00:00'
```

Amazing! Just in one call!

Comment: I like the `date -d '02:00:00 next second -2 seconds'`, good one! To fulfill the OPs requirement you may need to add `+'%H:%M:%S'`.

Comment: @fedorqui, Well, I have removed that one because you can get ``-1 seconds`` in front and the problem is solved. The requirement is fulfilled because ``+%T`` is the same as ``+%H:%M:%S``

Answer (score -1):

Update: **This was a JOKE!**

Just run this bash job in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    mv /var/current-time /var/time-one-second-ago
    date > /var/current-time
    sleep 1
done
```

Start it up when your machine starts, eg by using /etc/init.d

When you want the time one second ago, just do

```
cat /var/time-one-second-ago
```

Comment: Seems like this would be ~ 50/50 on getting one second ago/two seconds ago, but creative and probably shouldn't be getting downvotes (especially in absence of comments).